# how function return 2nd and 4th value using collection in oracle? answer would be 42 and 46

Tags: function, plsql, collections

It will display 4th collection value. i want second and fourth.

```
create or replace function temp_fun_2 return number as
    TYPE t1 IS table of number;
    emp_tab t1 ;
BEGIN
    emp_tab := t1(12, 42, 39, 46, 57, 62, 11, 35, 98);
    return emp_tab(4);
end;
/
```

Comment: Returning multiple things will require using OUT parameters or returning a collection type with multiple members.

Comment: or change the return type to varchar2 and return emp_tab(2) || ',' || emp_tab(4) to return a comma delimited string with the two values in it.  Would need to know more about what you are trying to actually achieve to know which solution would work best for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  After compiling the above function. it return output '46'  using "select (temp_fun_2) from dual;" i want output   22 and   46. one below the other. it mean first it will return second collection value then fourth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your comment:

> i want output 22 and 46. one below the other

(by the way it's `42` not `22`!)

I guess, that you are looking for `Table functions` or `Pipelined Table functions`

So, this should work:

```
CREATE TYPE t_row AS object   (
  id           NUMBER
);
/

CREATE TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF t_row;
/


create or replace function temp_fun_2 return t_tab PIPELINED as
    TYPE t1 IS table of number;
    emp_tab t1 ;
BEGIN
    emp_tab := t1(12, 42, 39, 46, 57, 62, 11, 35, 98);
    PIPE ROW(t_row(emp_tab(2)));
    PIPE ROW(t_row(emp_tab(4)));
    return;
end;


select * from table(temp_fun_2)
```

result:

```
42
46
```

Comment: can u please explain what is difference between "select (temp_fun_2) from dual;" and  "select * from table(temp_fun_2)"